# Getting variables from string

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

For a modular application on CodeIgniter I would like to use the following code to get HMVC to work:

```
{modulename limit="x" start="y" template="z"}
```

I've tried to use the following:

```
preg_match_all('/{module}/', $page, $match)
preg_match_all('/{module(\S+)}/', $page, $match))
```

Does anyone have the solution?

Comment: what do you want to get from it?

Comment: I want the posibility for the administrator of the website to use these codes in textareas to load modules, like projects and galleries, dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want to get values for `limit, start, template` variables.

You can get all values using

```
    $x = '{modulename limit="x" start="y" template="z"}';
    preg_match_all('/(?<=\")\w+(?=\")/', $x, $matches);
    var_dump($matches);
```

You will get output

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "x"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "y"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "z"
  }
}
```

First positive lookbehind will match all `\w+` that preceded by `"` and second positive lookahead matches all `\w+` that is followed by a `"`. So all your values must be between double quotes.

Please check documentation about [Regular-Expressions Lookahead and Lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).